# PhpStorm: Disabling autofill on Find

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

A few versions ago, PhpStorm (and I assume WebStorm) added a new feature: Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find) while having text highlighted, automatically puts that text in the search bar:

[image]

Unfortunately, after decades of habit, I automatically press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and invariably end up with this:

[image]

Before anyone suggests I simply adapt and change, I'd like to point out that no other application I use behaves this way, and I don't want to develop a habit that will only cause me pain in other applications.

How can I disable this "helpful" feature in PhpStorm?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such options (could not find either in Settings or Registry). Not sure about your OS and settings .. but here on Windows 10 and PhpStorm 2016.3.2 using Default keymap and with my setup IDE preselects text that is currently entered in Find field (regardless if find bar is already shown or not) so using `Ctrl+V` after `Ctrl+F` is not a problem at all. (*just an idea*) Try with non Darcula GUI Theme and with all 3rd party plugins disabled -- maybe one of them is causing this?

Comment: **P.S.** I have tried all the above in `.php` file, but in `.js` and in `.html` it behaves differently -- just like you describe -- it does not pre-select existing text if invoking `Ctrl+F` with selected text under caret. Not sure why PHP is treated differently. Can you please verify that? **P.P.S.** tried again ... it now behaves the same in ALL files... crazy stuff.

Comment: @LazyOne It's definitely a "feature", and it was implemented several versions back. I've been putting up with it for ages, but I felt like finally fixing it today. Darn :(

Comment: If you will find no answer here .. please try forums (e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm) or asking support team directly ("Submit a request" link on top of that page) -- I would like to know how to make text in search field always preselected as well (especially considering that it worked for me at first -- and I have tried a lot of different scenarios in .php files before writing that comment .. and then it stopped working for me ...)

Comment: I got in touch with them directly. Unfortunately it's not possible :(

Comment: Vote for this issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167955

Comment: @GridTrekkor Thanks, done!

Comment: Hurray ... marked as "fixed" now :)